# Submit a PySpark job to a cluster with Spark --jars option

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I would like to be able to specify the --jars PySpark submit option when I submit a PySpark job. However this option is not supported. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising this issue, it appears you discovered a bug where we haven't yet wired out the necessary flag; the intent is indeed to provide a `--jars` option available in both the console GUI and in `gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark`, and we'll hopefully be able to deploy a fix in the next minor release within a few weeks.

In the meantime, you can try simply dumping any jarfile dependencies into `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/` on your master node and/or your worker nodes, possibly using [initialization actions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/init-actions) to automate downloading the jarfiles at cluster-deployment time, and then it will be available on the classpaths of your Spark (and Hadoop) jobs automatically.